# Check if administration toolbar is visible

Tags: 7, toolbar

How can I check in a theme-file.tpl.php if the administration toolbar is visible or not?

The easiest, but not nicest way to check that, if the user has certain user roles. But is there a way to check that, without checking the roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using the [user_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7) function to see if they have the "access toolbar" permission should work.

Some example code:

```
if (user_access('access toolbar')) {
  // Your logic here.
}
```